# Angular: How to configure 'ng serve' command to open an Incognito Mode browser?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli-v7

**I want to open my project in an Incognito Mode browser so that no cache is stored.**

**Is there an Angular CLI flag that can be added to the `ng serve -o` command or to the Angular CLI configuration file that will support opening a browser in Incognito Mode?**

I don't want to type my URL by opening the browser changing to incognito. I could disable cache and cookies, but I use youtube and other sites which would make for a reduced development experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular's CLI internally uses [`opn` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn) when you pass that `-o` flag.

Currently, the CLI doesn't support passing more options to the `opn` package, therefore it will open the site using your system's default browser.

Feel free to file an issue in the CLI's repo - or even contribute to the project!

> Source: [Angular CLI code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/78f5c287d840c1411e2dce028afba3b02c10d868/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/dev-server/index.ts#L144) (at the time of answer)